# Java 8 filter by attribute

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a class which is of the following definition

```
public class MyClass {
  int val;
  type t;
}
```

Where type is an enum with values A,B,C,D,....

I have a list of objects of MyClass and I want to filter out the first element of each type occurring in the list.

for example :-

Given list:

```
{{1,A},{2,A},{4,B},{5,B},{3,C}}
```

Output:

```
{{1,A},{4,B},{3,C}}
```

Is there a way to use filter() of a stream of the list to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this with a single `Stream` pipeline, but you can do it with two.

The first pipeline groups the objects by the `val` property (producing a `Map<Integer,List<MyClass>>`) and the second takes the first object of each `List` produced by the first pipeline and collects them into the output `List`:

```
List<MyClass>
  filtered = mycl.stream ()
                 .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (c -> c.val))
                 .values ()
                 .stream ()
                 .map (l -> l.get (0))
                 .collect (Collectors.toList ());
```

Comment: There is no need to collect the groups into `List`s, just to retrieve the first element of each. Just consider, `Collectors.toMap(c - > c.val, c -> c, (prev, next) -> prev)`. Since the resulting map’s values need no conversion then, you can do everything in a single stream operation: `Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(c - > c.val, c -> c, (prev, next) -> prev), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which is not as elegant I hoped for but it works:

```
 Set<MyType> typeSet = new HashSet<>();
    List<MyClass> result = list.stream()
            .filter(c -> typeSet.add(c.getType())).collect(
                    Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any direct way of doing it but you can achieve it by doing

1) First use streams's findFirst method with filter (TypeOf type).
2) do above steps for all types.
3) Merge all above data into one list.

Answer (score 0):

One of good way to achieve this override equals() and hashCode() in your MyClass class. Check equality on the basis of 'type'.  Then put your List in Set it will remove all duplicate. :)